# How can I formulate the 3-SAT problem as a 0-1 Linear integer program?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, linear-programming, approximation, linear-approximation

I understand the 3-Sat problem but I do not understand 0-1 Linear Integer Program. I know in a linear integer program I would have an indicator variable $X_i$ that indicates whether a clause is true or not, and I want to maximize this? Can someone show me how to represent this problem as a 0-1 Linear Integer program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two versions of the Integer Linear Program problem: a decision version and an optimization version. The decision version just asks if there's *any* integer solution to the set of equations; the optimization problem asks if there's a solution that optimizes/maximizes some objective function.

The **decision** version ("is there any integer solution to this set of equations") is the one that's equivalent to 3SAT. (Note that 3SAT itself is a decision problem, asking whether there is any solution).

If that's all the direction you need to get started, feel free to ignore the rest  of this answer.

---

Here's how to reduce 3SAT to ILP:

1. You're given a 3SAT problem in the form of variables like $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ and three-term clauses involving those variables, like $a_1 = (x_1 \vee \overline x_4 \vee \overline{x_7})$. A solution to a 3SAT problem is an assignment of boolean values to the variables $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ in such a way that every clause is true.
2. You can make a corresponding ILP problem.

   - For each variable $x_i$ in the 3SAT problem, there's a variable $z_i$ in the ILP problem.
   - By default, the variables in an ILP problem can be assigned any integer value. To force each variable $z_i$ to be 0 or 1 (instead of just any integer), you can introduce the constraints
     $$0 \leq z_1 \leq 1$$
     $$0 \leq z_2 \leq 1$$
     $$\vdots$$
     $$0 \leq z_n \leq 1$$
     to the ILP problem.
   - Now we have to translate the boolean clauses like $a = (x_1 \vee \overline x_4 \vee \overline{x_7})$ into integer linear equations. We can translate them systematically like this:
     $$x_1 \vee \overline{x_4} \vee \overline{x_7} \quad\iff\quad z_1 + (1-z_4) + (1-z_7) > 0$$
     Here, we've replaced every negated term $\overline{x_i}$ with $(1-z_i)$; we've replaced every un-negated term $x_j$ with $z_j$; and we've replaced bitwise-or $(\vee)$ with addition (+).  This works because our earlier constraints already force the $z_i$ to be 0 or 1, so $(1-z_i)$ has the same effect as bitwise negation, and the sum of a bunch of terms is 0 if all of them is 0, or positive if any of them is positive.
   - Using this translation strategy, you can add a new linear constraint to the ILP for every clause in the 3SAT problem.
   - The two problems are now equivalent: there's an integer solution to this ILP if and only if there's a boolean solution to the original 3SAT problem.

---

An example instance of a 3SAT decision problem:

> Is there an assignment of boolean values to the variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ such that the clauses $$A = (x_1 \vee \overline{x_3}\vee x_4)$$ and $$B = (\overline{x_1}\vee \overline{x_2} \vee x_3)$$ are simultaneously satisfied?

The corresponding equivalent ILP instance:

> Is there an assignment of integer values to the variables $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ such that the linear equations:
>     \begin{align*} 
>   0 & \leq z_1 \leq 1 & \\
>   0 & \leq z_2 \leq 1  &\\
>   0 & \leq z_3 \leq 1  & \\
>   0 & \leq z_4 \leq 1 & \\
>  \\
>   &z_1 + (1-z_3) + z_4 > 0 & \qquad [A]\\
>   &(1-z_1) + (1-z_2) + z_3 > 0 & \qquad [B]
>   \end{align*}
>   are simultaneously satisfied?

Comment: ok great, I understand most of that. But what is the 'new linear constraints' you are talking about.  So in short I want to maximize the sum of all the clauses, with each clause containing an $z$'s that will add up to $1$ if the clause is true? If you can can you state this formally? Thanks!

Comment: I just added an example. Note that nothing is being maximized; we need all of the equations to be satisfied, and that's enough. Each clause will add up to a *positive integer* (not necessarily 1) when the variables make it true, or zero when the variables make it false.

Comment: Is it a 0-1 linear integer program then? Or just a linear integer program

Comment: Well, it's a general integer linear program at first, but you add the constraints $0 \leq z_i \leq 1$ which makes it into a 0-1 linear integer program, I suppose.

Comment: What is the objective you try to optimize here? I know that any feasible solution of the ILP is a solution to the 3SAT, but to actually solve the ILP, we need an objective function.

Comment: This particular integer programming problem is really more about feasibility than optimality. Because the vars are all boolean, we don't have to worry about them becoming too large --- a trivial optimization fn like $\max_\mathbf{x} \mathbf{c}^\top\mathbf{x}$ where $\mathbf{c} = [0,0,0,\ldots,0]$ should be enough (it's zero everywhere, hence trivially maximal everywhere).